# How to make a flowchart/diagram using only HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, flowchart

I need to make a really complicated diagram for a website, in which the hierarchy will be a bit messy: arrows will go up and down, sometimes an element will point to several others, and sometimes there will be several elements pointing to the same one. I have found [this method](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree), but it doesn't allow more than one parent for an element and therefore won't do the trick in this case.

It has to be done in HTML/CSS, because my intention is to add some Javascript to change the content of the blocks dinamically.

This is an example of the level of complexity I need to achieve:
[image: chart]

Comment: All of this elements can be created and positioned in pure HTML/CSS by using tags, pseudoelements (like `:before`), css3 transformations and absolute positioning, but keep in mind that it won't be much of a cross browser solution and it'll definitely take a lot of work. :)

Comment: did you look at this http://astuteo.com/slickmap/ is it the same deal? i didn't really go through

Comment: @nd_macias Your solution sounds solid. However, I don't think I have neither the time nor the CSS skills to do it that way. I'll have to keep looking. Thanks though.

Comment: @btevfik That link only works for unordered lists, which are way too simple for this chart.

Comment: i don't think you are going to find a pure css solution to this. it seems way complicated for css to handle.

Comment: You can create a diagram in HTML5 or SVG and still manipulate it with Javscript.

Comment: This is probably impossible in pure HTML and CSS since an element can have only one parent in HTML.

Comment: You might benefit by reviewing flowchart-related pens on codepen. http://codepen.io/search/pens/?q=flowchart&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Answer (score 17):

You might want to take a look at this

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree

Comment: he already said that doesnt work for him

Answer (score 6):

Another to look for is SpaceTree [example](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html) by "Nicolas Garcia Belmonte" but not a pure CSS solution. It is compatible with IE and most of browsers. Definitely worth a try.

Comment: Ok, can I ask to the awesome person who says this was not useful? can (s)he please told us why (s)he thinks this was not useful? I have delivered a small project using this and was so much fun to work with this one. I agree it is not super flexible but can be changed to suit your need.