# Flowchart framework for a college curriculum

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new at here (sorry for my poor English)

I am looking for tools/frameworks to create a dynamic flowchart for the curriculum of an undergraduate course. At first, a JSON will be taken from a backend and building the front end from it.

I've researched a lot and the only one I found was GoJS, but it has a paid license.

It would be something like that [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flowchart/diagram using only HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567278/how-to-make-a-flowchart-diagram-using-only-html-and-css)

Comment: Maybe, the scenario of this question contains "one root", it's not my case